# What is nr_swiches in /proc/sched_debug ? How to get system-wide voluntary and involuntary context switches on Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, kernel, proc

What does nr_swiches represent in /proc/sched_debug  on Linux ? 
How to get system-wide voluntary and involuntary context switches on Linux ?